# Implementing hashCode() and equals() in class with no fields

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have an abstract class which will be used in a Hashtable:

```
public abstract class CEvent {

    abstract public void finished();
}
```

How to implement hashCode() if it does not have any field, only methods?
Should i rely on Object implementation of hashCode?

Comment: Ask yourself when you wish two different  `CEvent` instances to be considered equal to each other. If the answer is never, don't override `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: You could declare them as abstract to force any child class to override them. If you feel that the default behavior is enough, leave it as it is.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if you have found that provides a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you can use the following as the default behaviour:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   return this == o || o instanceof CEvent;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return CEvent.class.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: So two objects are equal for you when they have the same type `CEvent`? You are mixing up type equality with object/instance equality

Comment: @HannesSchneidermayer that depends on your needs.
If you would like to have same hashCode and check different objects for equality - than it is a nice approach.

Also I am interested, how would you implement equals for class without fields.

Comment: I would suggest modifying the result of `getClass().hashcode()` because it would class with it. Add a random int (also maybe multiplied by a prime like 31).

Answer (score 8):

If the class is abstract, then it must have concrete subclasses. You implement the hash code method in the concrete subclasses.

You should ensure that `hashCode()` is consistent with `equals()`. If two objects are considered equal they should return the same hash code. See the Java documentation on object for more details.

[hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

You can implement `hashCode` in the abstract class if it can obtain the information required for hashing from abstract methods. The Java class `AbstractList` does this. However, you will need to be happy that by default, different derived classes will inherit that method and will return the same hash code for similar data. In your case, it does not make sense to implement the `hashCode` function in the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Just use super class(Object) equals and hascode implementation in this case. this will have no effect on your code as you dont have anything to compare.